# Inserting in map<string, STRUCT> error

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a map with the struct defined as under:

```
struct kv_string {
        std::string value;
        long long exp_time;
        kv_string(const std::string& v): value(v), exp_time(-1) {}
};
```

Now when I'm trying to insert a new structure using

```
else if(qargs[0] == "set"){
    if(qargs.size()==3){
        kv_map.insert(std::make_pair( qargs[1], kv_string(qargs[2])));
    }
}
```

(qargs is a `vector<string>`), I get the following error:

```
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61:0,
>                      from structures.h:5:
>     /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h: In instantiation of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key,
> _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = kv_string; _Compare =
> std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc =
> std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, kv_string> >;
> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = kv_string;
> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type =
> std::basic_string<char>]’:
>     /usr/include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:281:48:   required from here
>     /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:469:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘kv_string::kv_string()’
>                __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
>                                                                ^
>     /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:469:59: note: candidates are:
>     structures.h:11:9: note: kv_string::kv_string(const string&)
>              kv_string(const std::string& v): value(v), exp_time(-1) {}
>              ^
>     structures.h:11:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>     structures.h:8:8: note: kv_string::kv_string(const kv_string&)
>      struct kv_string {
>             ^
>     structures.h:8:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
>     make: *** [server_main.o] Error 1
```

I have also tried adding an additional constructor `kv_string(){}`, but it gives a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
kv_map.insert(std::make_pair(qargs[1], kv_string(qargs[2]));
```

Or this:

```
kv_map.emplace(qargs[1], kv_string(qargs[2]);
```

Or, in C++17:

```
kv_map.try_emplace(qargs[1], qargs[2]);
```

The `[]`-operator *default-initializes* a new element (if one doesn't exist for the given key), but your type `kv_string` is not default-constructible. So you cannot use that operator. The above operations are more powerful than the `[]`-operator, too: they return an iterator to the element at the key, and information about whether the key already existed.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that the problem could be here!

Comment: But using this is giving me a Segmentation fault.

Comment: @AyushGupta: So you probably have some bugs in some parts of code you haven't showed.

Comment: @Mr.C64 I didnt have any problems with the code anywhere else. When I enter this else if statement, I get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ compiler emitted this error message complaining about the **lack** of a **default constructor** for your `kv_string` class:

> ```
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:469:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘kv_string::kv_string()’
>            __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
> ```

If you read the [documentation for `std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), you'll see that the mapped type (in your case `kv_string`) must be *default-constructible*.

So, if it makes sense for your own design, you could just add a default constructor to your `kv_string` struct:

```
struct kv_string {
    // ...

    // Default constructor
    kv_string() : exp_time(-1 /* or whatever default value */) {}
};
```

As a side note, I would also mark your `kv_string(const std::string&)` constructor as `explicit`, to avoid implicit conversions from `string`s.

Comment: This seems like terrible advice. You don't generally want to add non-semantic noise to your interface to enable a meaningless and dangerous broken library expression somewhere. Just don't use that library API!

Comment: @KerrekSB: Your comment seems arrogant and as such stupid. Reserve the word "terrible" for your own stuff. If this is the style adopted on StackOverflow, that's a recipe for a failed community (actually, anti-community). Learn to be polite even when you disagree. If in the OP's design a default constructor makes sense, he can add it and continue using the `[]`-operator, which is much more readable than other forms like `std::map::insert(std::make_pair(...))`, although I know the latter carries more information in the returned pair (assuming in the OP's code that information is relevant).

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with readers coming across this and picking up habits. It's nothing personal.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I honestly think `[]`-operator allows writing very readable code, but I'm aware other methods are more versatile. I think it's the OP's choice whether making his class default-constructible to be able to use `[]` or not, basing on his own design. FWIW I upvoted your answer since I think it's well written and contains useful information.

Comment: Thanks. Well, operator[] does sometimes look nice, that's true, but unfortunately the map interface is a bit weird, and the operator not often appropriate. I'd really like to avoid suggesting to design your classes to work with certain library constructs. All too often people mangle semantics and violate requirements when they "just want to stick the type in a set", rather than designing the type to do what it was meant to do, and then worry about using it in containers later. A principled approach to design is very hard to teach...